# Unable to create Android Virtual Device in Visual Studio Xamarin Tools

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Virtualbox VM with Windows 10 and

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 Preview Version 15.6.0 Preview
>   5.0 VisualStudio.15.Preview/15.6.0-pre.5.0+27413.0 Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.7.02558

with Xamarin Tools for VS

> Xamarin   4.9.0.730 (c06c7fdd0) Visual Studio extension to enable
>   development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.
>
> Xamarin Designer   4.10.53 (0f268fa65) Visual Studio extension to
>   enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.
>
> Xamarin.Android SDK   8.2.0.12 (HEAD/413eed680) Xamarin.Android
>   Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
>
> Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   11.8.0.18 (4c56cbb) Xamarin.iOS and
>   Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

I know that I can't run x86 base emulator in a VM, but what I am trying to achieve is to run an arm base emulator which should be possible as it doesn't need hardware acceleration.

However, trying to create a new AVD (any AVD) always fails. Below some screenshots showing the Android setup and the errors

[image: Android SDK Manager]

[image: Android SDK Manager]

[image: Android Emulator Manager]

[image: Android Emulator Manager]

Finally the [Log Report](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Asf--g2ep0Ji2Bm9spGXhPPtvBCO)

**EDIT:**
Please note that I am not asking for workarounds or advice (at this stage at least).

- I know that non accelerated emulators are slow
- I know that there are potential workarounds (Android Studio AVD manager, CLI avdmanager...)

I am using a tooling (Visual Studio + Xamarin Tools for Visual Studio) which is supposed to work in a certain way, but it doesn't seem to. Either I am doing something wrong, or there is a bug somewhere. So I expect answers like:

"This is a known issue of ..... and will be solved in a future release of the product"
or

"Your setup is incorrect, change to ...."
or

"What you are doing is not supported, see ...."

Comment: The Xamarin device manager is just calling the `avdmanager.bat` with all the params preset, try running it directly from the cmd-line using the cmd-line options that are present in the log report and see what happens and if you get a more verbose error.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `avdmanager` CLI directly or even Android Studio's AVD Manager to unblock you(I replied to your Developer Community item earlier).The scenario of running an AVD inside a VM(let alone an ARM image) is notoriously slow and potentially a waste of time given how bad the performance can be. You would be better off driving to the local electronics store and picking up a physical device as the time for it to actually boot would be comparable.

Comment: @JonDouglas `You would be better off driving...` LOL, I need a good laugh today, thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience i wouldn't recommend running any emulators within the VM, try and run the AVD on your host machine and connect it to the VM. [Example using genymotion](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17074/development-in-vmware-genymotion-in-virtualbox)